# cannot run docker on windows 10

Tags: windows, docker, containers

hello I just installed docker for windows on a windows 10 computer.

```
docker run -d -p 8787:8787 rocker/rstudio
```

gives me:

> docker: error during connect: Post
>   http://%2F%2F.%2Fpipe%2Fdocker_engine/v1.35/containers/create: open
>   //./pipe/docker_engine: The system cannot find the file specified. In
>   the default daemon configuration on Windows, the docker client must be
>   run elevated to connect. This error may also indicate that the docker
>   daemon is not running. See 'docker run --help'

What I have done so far:

1. installed https://download.docker.com/win/stable/Docker%20for%20Windows%20Installer.exe
2. enabled virtualization in the BIOS
3. made sure that hyper-v is enabled

Comment: Cant advise on current error but Docker ALWAYS had problems on windows. Personally had problems which had no solution on Windows. I would advise you to look towards ubuntu.

Comment: This may sound obvious, but did you make sure you were running `docker for windows.exe` and `dockercli.exe` as Admin?